# How to access data object in a HTMLElement without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, ecmascript-5

In my web-application, I have binded jQuery keyboard to a textbox. And I want to call `keyboard.close()` function explicitly on the keyboard since I'm removing all the eventListeners to the textfield at the start.

I can call this function using jQuery, like below.

```
$('#chat-form').data('keyboard').close();
```

But I'm not allowed to use jQuery because of some memory issues. Is there anyway that I can access data object in a HTMLElement, without jQuery?

Unfortunately, `elem.dataset.keyboard` and `elem.getAttribute('data-keyboard')` is not working as well. but `$(elem).data('keyboard')` is working fine.

Comment: Use `dataset`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset. Although you should note this returns a string. Presumably you'll need to deserialise that string before you call `close()` on it (which is something jQuery does by default)

Answer (score 3):

You can use as below;

```
var elem = document.getElementById('elId');
console.log(elem.dataset.<your-data-attribute-without-data-prefix>)
```

Comment: To elaborate: `elem.dataset.keyboard` which corresponds to `data-keyboard`.

Comment: How can you call `close()` on the string result of `dataset`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you have cast it.